# Trim in a Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Pyspark dataframe(**Original Dataframe**) having below data(all columns have string datatype). In my use case i am not sure of what all columns are there in this input dataframe. User just pass me the name of dataframe and ask me to trim all the columns of this dataframe. Data in a typical dataframe looks like as below:

```
  id              Value         Value1
   1               "Text "       "Avb"
   2               1504         " Test"
   3               1               2
```

Is there anyway i can do it without being dependent on what all columns are present in this dataframe and get all the column trimmed in this dataframe. Data after trimming aall the columns of dataframe should look like.

```
   id             Value        Value1
   1               "Text"       "Avb"
   2               1504         "Test"
   3               1               2
```

Can someone help me out? How can i achieve it using Pyspark dataframe? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Using ***trim()*** function in @osbon123's answer.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import trim

for c_name in df.columns:
    df = df.withColumn(c_name, trim(col(c_name)))
```

Answer (score 2):

input:

```
df.show()

+---+-----+------+
| id|Value|Value1|
+---+-----+------+
|  1|Text |   Avb|
|  2| 1504|  Test|
|  3|    1|     2|
+---+-----+------+
```

Code:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func
for col in df.columns:
    df = df.withColumn(col, func.ltrim(func.rtrim(df[col])))
```

Output:

```
df.show()

+---+-----+------+
| id|Value|Value1|
+---+-----+------+
|  1| Text|   Avb|
|  2| 1504|  Test|
|  3|    1|     2|
+---+-----+------+
```

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid using `withColumn` because it creates a new `DataFrame` which is time-consuming for very large dataframes. I created the following function based on this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66381648/1715556), but now it works with any dataframe even when it has string and non-string columns.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def trim_string_columns(of_data: DataFrame) -> DataFrame:
  data_trimmed = of_data.select([
    (F.trim(c.name).alias(c.name) if isinstance(c.dataType, StringType) else c.name) for c in of_data.schema
  ])
  return data_trimmed
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the cleanest (and most computationally efficient) way I've seen it done to trim all spaces in all columns. If you want underscores to replace spaces, simply replace `""` with `"_"`.

```
# Standardize Column names no spaces to underscore
new_column_name_list = list(map(lambda x: x.replace(" ", ""), df.columns))
df = df.toDF(*new_column_name_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dtypes function in DataFrame API to get the list of Cloumn Names along with their Datatypes and then for all string columns use "trim" function to trim the values.

Regards,

Neeraj