# pySpark 3.0 how to trim spaces for all columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

For this dataframe: How to trim all leading and trailing spaces for each column in a loop?

```
    df = spark.createDataFrame(
        [
            (' a', '10 ', ' b '), # create your data here, be consistent in the types.
        ],
        ['col1', 'col2','col3'] # add your columns label here
    )
    df.show(5)
```

I know how to do that by specifing each column like below, but need to do that for all columns in a loop because in real case i will not know the column names and how many of the columns.

```
    from pyspark.sql.functions import trim
    df = df.withColumn("col2", trim(df.col2))
    df.show(5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to apply `trim` to all columns:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import trim, col
df2 = df.select([trim(col(c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns])
```

Comment: It should work.  P.S for spark 2.x, should use trim(col(c)). Ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52596712/how-do-i-use-trim-in-pyspark-2-x

Comment: @thotwielder yes you're right, I've edited my answer to correct for this.